# Not able to see &lt; character in front end

Tags: wysiwyg

I am running into a problem when creating content with the < character… It is quite strange as the symbol is showed in the backend, when creating the content, but it disappear when you go to /node/%nid. Actually the whole  text nodes, where the symbol is, disappears. I have disabled all the filters and the problem remains…

By the way, I have a Drupal 7 installation and cKeditor module installed, but switching to plain text editor doesn't make a difference.

Does someone has a clue of why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

After some tests, I have discovered where the problem comes from. It has to do with the ["word link"](https://drupal.org/project/word_link) module. When word link is configured to run on a field, then it seems to remove all the text within the scope of the tags where the < appears. Now it seems it's time to surf the word link code...

Comment: FYI, disabling filters does not affect existing content - it needs to be re-saved in order to get the filter changes to take effect.

Comment: Jose can you give example of the "content" you're entering and also the filter being used with it?

Comment: Ok, I've been trying to isolate the problem with no success, it just seem to happen in some fields randomly. AgA, let's say I've got a Content type: "Problem" with 2 fields, "statement" and "Solution". When I write <p>A text for the statement &lt;<p>, the proper symbol is shown on the front end (url /node/%nid). When I write the exact same content in the solution field (of the same type as statement), the text within the scope of the tag where the character appear is gone. Hope it is clear enough.. If you need further clarification, let me know. I keep on testing

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I found a work around for the problem. In the word link configuration form we can find a "Disallowed html tags" input text box. We can add a  tag there, so now, whenever I want to include the < character in my text, I wrapp the  tag around it.

I know it is not the cleanest solution but it is enough to keep going until they fix the module.

Hope it can help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

hey i have identified a scenario where this happens; if < or < is written without any space before and after this character then this ommited the whole line. Don't know why is it happening but works fine with leading and trailing space

Comment: Hi wajeeha khalid, 

Yes, I found out a work around using span tags. When we were searching for the reason, we found out it had to do with the way wordlink parses tags. If my memory serves me correctly, it identifies '<' as an html opening tag (even when using '&lt;'). 

If I ever go deeper, I will let you know!